# DBSCAN not working properly

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan

I am implementing DBSCAN in java. I have followed the algorithm given over [here (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN). I think I have it right but for some reason only 1 cluster is formed. 
The Java code looks like

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>> dbcluster = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Node> points; // this contains my data assume
int min =10, esp =50;
int clustcount =0;
for(int i=0;i<points.size();i++){               
    Node tempdb = points.get(i);                
    if(tempdb.visited==false){
        tempdb.visited=true;
        ArrayList<Node> myNeighbors = getNeigbhors(tempdb,points, esp);
        if(myNeighbors.size() < min){
            tempdb.noise = true;
        }else{
            //ArrayList<Node> tempclust = new ArrayList<>();
            dbcluster.add(new ArrayList<Node>());
            expandCluster(tempdb,points,myNeighbors,dbcluster,esp,min,clustcount);
            clustcount++;
        }
}

public static ArrayList<Node> getNeigbhors(Node p ,ArrayList<Node> data,int  esp){
        ArrayList<Node> tempReturn =  new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
            Node temptemp = data.get(i);            
            if(p.x != temptemp.x && p.y !=temptemp.y){
                double distance =Math.sqrt(((p.x - temptemp.x)*(p.x - temptemp.x))+((p.y - temptemp.y)*(p.y - temptemp.y)));
                if(distance <=esp){
                    tempReturn.add(temptemp);
                }
            }
        }       
        return tempReturn;      
}

public static void expandCluster(Node p, ArrayList<Node> data, ArrayList<Node> N, ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>> allCluster,int esp, int min,int clustcount){

    //ArrayList<Node> tempSmallClust = new ArrayList<>();
    //tempSmallClust.add(p);
    allCluster.get(clustcount).add(p);
    for(int i=0;i<N.size();i++){
        Node tempP = N.get(i);
        if(tempP.visited == false){
            tempP.visited=true;
            ArrayList<Node> tempNewNeighbors = new ArrayList<>();
            tempNewNeighbors = getNeigbhors(tempP, data, esp);
            if(tempNewNeighbors.size() >= min){
                ArrayList<Node> tempN=new ArrayList<>();
                tempN=mergeNeighbors(N, tempNewNeighbors);
                N = new ArrayList<>();
                N=tempN;                    
            }
        }
        if(!checkInCluster(tempP,allCluster)) {
            allCluster.get(clustcount).add(tempP);
        }
     }          
    //return tempSmallClust;
}

public static boolean checkInCluster(Node p, ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>> allCluster){

    for(int i=0;i<allCluster.size();i++){           
        ArrayList<Node> tempList = allCluster.get(i);
        if(tempList.contains(p)){                
            return true;
        }           
    }
    return false;
}

public static ArrayList<Node> mergeNeighbors(ArrayList<Node> N,ArrayList<Node> NewN){
    ArrayList<Node> tmpR = N;
    for(int i=0;i<NewN.size();i++){
        if(!N.contains(NewN.get(i))){
            tmpR.add(NewN.get(i));
        }
    }       
    return tmpR;
}
```

The node class is simple with int x int y and boolean noise and visited.
the data is provided here [here data](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~tmh/courses/dataMining/20123/data1.txt)

Comment: There is a tool called "debugger", did you debug your code already?

Comment: Please indent your codes, and show only relevant sections of the codes that you think aren't working.

Comment: Yes I did debug. there are no error. I dont know which part is going wrong here now

Answer (score 1):

Your data is uniform distributed.

**There are no clusters in this data set.**

IMHO the correct of putting everything in one cluster (if eps too high and minpts too low) is correct, or putting everything into noise (if eps and minpts set appropriately).

So maybe it's not an implementation error, but your data is not appropriate.